# TFS plugin locks file on edit

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Hi I am using MS TFS as my repository, i have tsf everywhere plugin installed on eclipse juno, here whenever I make an edit in a file, the file gets auto locked in repository and then only after I commit, another developer is able to commit, is there any way to avoid locking, as we have in SVN, i mean edit won't lock the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your team project configuration, in "source control settings", you need to check "Enable multiple check-out". You also need to check in your team project collection settings if "file merging" is enabled for your file extensions.